# How to get the hdfs usage report in details

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, bigdata

We got hdfs of capacity 900TB. As the data stored is growing a lot its difficult to keep track of what is useful and what could be deleted. 
I want to analyze hdfs usage for following pattern so that the capacity could be used optimally.

1. What is the frequently accessed data.
2. Data not being touched/accessed for long time (Possible candidate for deletion)
3. Data usage distribution by users.
4. Active users.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive that data from:

- (1) HDFS audit log (access patterns per user/ip)
- (2) fsimage (access times per file, data not accessed)

(1) Do you have HDFS audit log enabled? Read more [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToConfigure).

(2) To start with fsimage read [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html) - there is an example to get "Data not being touched/accessed for long time"

You may also want to consider [HAR](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hadoop_archives.html) to archive the data (instead of delete) - thus reduce both storage usage and precious memory on the namenode.